# Hook constructor Object?

Tags: javascript

What I'd like to do is:
1. do something with Object (overwrite or set some property of it)
2. when I define an object like `{'a': 12}`, alert  "`'a':12`"
Is it possible?

Comment: No. that is a security risk. Naughty code could overwrite the Object constructor to send the object data to a naughty server. This would then steal _all your data_ on the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var obj = {'a': 12};

for (ind in obj ){
   alert("'"+ind+"': "+obj[ind]);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/nwrWq/

Comment: No no no, I mean when var obj = {'a': 12}; is executed, the alert happen

Comment: @wong2 -- what do you mean `when it is executed`?

Comment: That means, even if there are no for loop after it, I still see the alert, and that's because something was done with Object before the define of var obj.

Comment: @wong2 i really dont know what you mean. can you give a code sample of what you want to do in your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof Object.make !== 'function') {
    Object.make = function (o) {
        for(key in o) {
            if(o.hasOwnProperty(key))
                alert( key + ' ' + o[key]);   
        }
        return o;
    };
}

var MyObj = Object.make({ a: 1});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uc5Pj/